# How do I use the syntax of Turbo C++ while programming in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++11, codeblocks, turbo-c++

I am new to programming and my school uses **turbo C++**. I find it more convenient to work on the **CodeBlocks**' interface.

So, I'm curious if there is a way to code inside the CodeBlocks interface while using the syntax of Turbo C++. 
So that my school will still accept my code written in CodeBlocks.

Comment: Turbo C++ is a discontinued compiler, I suggest you don't get attached to anything related to it.

Comment: You could configure Code::Blocks to use Turbo C++ as a compiler

Comment: @M.M Could you please let me know how? That would be of great help!

Comment: Google for "how to add compiler to code blocks" but substitute turboc++ . (you'll have to figure out the details yourself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turbo C++ is obsolete.  It was discontinued in 1994 (23 years ago!), then re-released in a single newer version in 2006.  C++ wasn't even standardized until 1998, and it had a major update in 2011, and another important update in 2014.  No version of Turbo C++ supports the current version of C++.

I'd recommend: write your program in CodeBlocks or whatever other modern environment you prefer, and when you're done, copy it into Turbo C++ to try compiling and running it there.  If it doesn't work, make whatever changes you need in the Turbo C++ copy of the program so you can submit it for school, but keep the CodeBlocks version as the "real" version of your program.  Whatever differences there are, Turbo C++ is doing it the wrong way and CodeBlocks is (probably) doing it the right way.

And please tell your school that it's doing a disservice to its students by teaching with an obsolete compiler and outdated (possibly pre-standardized) version of the language.  Good modern compilers are freely available.

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, it can be used with any compiler (even Turbo C++'s compiler)